# Restrict search result to current site/web

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-search

My requirement is to search within sub site, if i am searching within a specific sub site result should come from current sub site. Here everything is working fine. But when I do advanced search it gives result from all site scope.

I can not create scope because we have more then 1000 sub site under one site collection and we have more then 50 site collections.

While I was looking at advanced search web part I don't see option for "Default to contextual scope" simile to search box web part.

I tried to set scope property of core result web part to "This Site" but its not working.

Comment: Are you using the out-of-the-box search results page or a custom page?  If you use a custom page, you might be able to restrict the results on the Search Core Results web part.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. I used "Path:{Site.URL}" to limit my search scope. BTW this is for SP2013(its company decision)

Answer (score 1):

Below query will limit search scope to the current site.

"Path:{Site.URL}"